# pass kwargs and default values to ordered list

Tags: python-2.7, list, tuples, keyword-argument

Using python 2.7, I have been researching into using keyword arguments to pass a function that inserts a new tuple into a list.

My goal: have a function that takes one required argument, and n number of arguments that then get inserted into a tuple at specific positions and have a default value if nothing was passed.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def add_tagging_log_row(key, **time_stamp):
    tagging_log_rows.insert(len(tagging_log_rows), (key, time_stamp.get('is_processed'), time_stamp.get('is_processed')))



add_tagging_log_row('zzz', is_processed=datetime.datetime.now(), is_audited=datetime.datetime.now())
```

Here is a sample of tagging_low_rows list I am building with all values in the tuple populated:

```
[('key1', datetime.datetime.now(), datetime.datetime.now(), datetime.datetime.now(), datetime.datetime.now()), ('key2', datetime.datetime.now(), datetime.datetime.now(), datetime.datetime.now(), datetime.datetime.now())]
```

here is the order of the items in each tuple in the list:

```
key | is_processed | is_archived | is_error | is_audited
```

The problem is when calling the function add_tagging_log_row(), I will always pass a 'key' but might or might not pass the other timestamp fields to the tuple when it is inserted into the list. I need these fields to be empty strings ('').

Is using **kwargs the right way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using `kwargs` works. You would need some exception handling inside your function though. `kwargs` passed in as a dictionary. You can check if a given timestamp exists in the dictionary and use an empty string if it doesn't. Try doing something like this inside the function:

```
timestamps_order = ['is_processed', 'is_archived', 'is_error', 'is_audited']
required_tuple = tuple([key] + [time_stamp[k] if k in time_stamp else "" for k in timestamps_order])
```

On a side note - please consider switching to Python 3. Python 2.7 is at the end of life and won't receive any future support. Most libraries have stopped supporting it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have to use python 2.7 as python 3 is not supported in AWS glue environment.